# SQL Server: fill a range with dates from overlapping intervals with priority

Tags: sql-server, date

I need to fill the range from 2017-04-01 to 2017-04-30 with the data from this table, knowing that the highest priority records should prevail over those with lower priorities

```
id     startValidity  endValidity  priority
-------------------------------------------
1004    2017-04-03    2017-04-30    1   
1005    2017-04-10    2017-04-22    2   
1010    2017-04-19    2017-04-23    3   
1006    2017-04-24    2017-04-28    2   
1008    2017-04-26    2017-04-28    3
```

In practice I would need to get a result like this:

```
id      startValidity  endValidity  priority
--------------------------------------------
1004    2017-04-03    2017-04-09    1   
1005    2017-04-10    2017-04-18    2   
1010    2017-04-19    2017-04-23    3   
1006    2017-04-24    2017-04-25    2   
1008    2017-04-26    2017-04-28    3   
1004    2017-04-29    2017-04-30    1
```

Comment: Please explain your question better with an example as to what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: The first recordset is the result of a cte that combines calendars related to an entity with parent entity calendars. 
Each record has a validity period and I need to get all the valid calendars over a given period (ie from 2017-04-01 to 2017-04-30) with contiguous validity periods (without overlapping), 
considering that, however, the calendars with higher priority must prevail over those with less priority

Comment: I guess that you cannot solve this with a single query, because the number of output records could be larger by any number than the input records. Most naturally it's solved recursively (because of the "framing" or "covering" or whatever you call it). Personally, I would write it in a higher level programming laguange (like C++, Java, C#) whenever possible.

Comment: Frankly not clear to me.Last record is not at all clear.Just explain the output in non technical terms.Do you hv that priority column in actual table.Can you change data and desire output ?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

can't think of anything elegant or more efficient solution right now . . .

```
-- Sample Table
declare @tbl table
(
    id      int,
    startValidity   date,
    endValidty  date,
    priority    int
)

-- Sample Data
insert into @tbl select 1004, '2017-04-03', '2017-04-30', 1
insert into @tbl select 1005, '2017-04-10', '2017-04-22', 2
insert into @tbl select 1010, '2017-04-19', '2017-04-23', 3
insert into @tbl select 1006, '2017-04-24', '2017-04-28', 2
insert into @tbl select 1008, '2017-04-26', '2017-04-28', 3

-- Query
; with 
date_range as -- find the min and max date for generating list of dates
(
    select  start_date = min(startValidity), end_date = max(endValidty)
    from    @tbl
),
dates as -- gen the list of dates using recursive CTE
(
    select  rn = 1, date = start_date
    from    date_range

    union all

    select  rn = rn + 1, date = dateadd(day, 1, d.date)
    from    dates d
    where   d.date  < (select end_date from date_range)
),
cte as -- for each date, get the ID based on priority
(
    select  *, grp = row_number() over(order by id) - rn
    from    dates d
            outer apply
            (
                select  top 1 x.id, x.priority
                from    @tbl x
                where   x.startValidity <= d.date
                and     x.endValidty    >= d.date
                order by x.priority desc
            ) t
)
-- final result
select  id, startValidity = min(date), endValidty = max(date), priority
from    cte
group by grp, id, priority
order by startValidity
```

Comment: I try to test with different data but it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Have a look at [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/) by Itzik Ben-Gan. It is not exactly what is asked for here, but I think Itzik's ideas may be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the purpose of Calendar CTE or table.
So I am not using any REcursive CTE or calendar.

May be I hvn't understood the requirement completly.

Try this with diff sample data,

```
declare @tbl table
(
    id      int,
    startValidity   date,
    endValidty  date,
    priority    int
)

-- Sample Data
insert into @tbl select 1004, '2017-04-03', '2017-04-30', 1
insert into @tbl select 1005, '2017-04-10', '2017-04-22', 2
insert into @tbl select 1010, '2017-04-19', '2017-04-23', 3
insert into @tbl select 1006, '2017-04-24', '2017-04-28', 2
insert into @tbl select 1008, '2017-04-26', '2017-04-28', 3
;With CTE as
(
select * ,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by startValidity)rn
from @tbl
)
,CTE1 as
(
select c.id,c.startvalidity,isnull(dateadd(day,-1, c1.startvalidity)
,c.endValidty) Endvalidity
,c.[priority],c.rn 
from cte c
left join cte c1
on c.rn+1=c1.rn
)

select  id,startvalidity,Endvalidity,priority from cte1
union ALL
select id,startvalidity,Endvalidity,priority from
(
select top 1 id,ca.startvalidity,ca.Endvalidity,priority from cte1
cross apply(
select top 1  
dateadd(day,1,endvalidity) startvalidity
,dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,endvalidity)+1,0)) Endvalidity
from cte1
order by rn desc)CA
order by priority
)t4
--order by startvalidity --if req
```